# preparedStatement SQL Error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Here is my code:

```
public int checklogin(String email, String key){
int res = -1;
try
{
    String selectSQL = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE email = ? AND key = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, key);

    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) 
        res = rs.getInt("id");

    rs.close();   
    preparedStatement.close();          
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

return res;
}
```

But i get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'AAA'' at line 1
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: It looks fine. Try running the SQL statement on its own in a query browser. Does that work?

Comment: Incidentally you should do the close() statements in a `finally` block, although that won't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: What is the value for email and key you are passing - yes, they're Strings, but do they have special characters in them that cause problems with the encoding?  Like Tim B says - it looks fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KEY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. It needs to be escaped

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE email = ? AND `key` = ?";
```

Avoiding the reserved keywords is always the best solution when naming column names.