# preparedStatement SQL error in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I get an error when I execute the following code.

```java
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from fpp_alarm"+ "where id = ? ");
preparedStatement.setString(1, id);   //string id = "4"
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The error is :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '4'' at line 1.
```

I have seen the similar questions here: [preparedStatement SQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232923/preparedstatement-sql-error)

But, I can't find the 'reserved word' of mysql in my code. It's also right when execute this query in mysql.

Comment: You are missing a space here `fpp_alarm"+ "where`

Comment: Snippets are only for HTML/JavaScript, don't use them in questions not related to HTML/JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When concatenated, you see that there is no space between `fpp_alarm` and `where` in your SQL statement.

```
select * from fpp_alarmwhere id = ?
```

Add that space in your SQL literal string, either after `fpp_alarm` or before `where`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no space between

```
pp_alarm"+ "wher
```

Should be 
`...pp_alarm" + " where ...`

Comment: @sparkon, then you will have query rendered like this "... pp_alarm where ..", right now it is rendered as ".. pp_alarmwhere .."

Comment: my bad its correct i dint notice the space before where.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that

```
String query="select * from fpp_alarm"+ "where id = ?";
```

when this gets evaluated it turns out to be like

```
select * from fpp_alarmwhere id = ? 
// the + sign concatenates the two pieces of String 
// into one with no space between them you can either solve it by doing this

String query="select * from fpp_alarm "+ "where id = ?"; // space after fpp_alarm
```

but I don't really see the use of + out here simply try like this

```
String query="select * from fpp_alarm where id = ?";
```